# Selecting data IN(subquery)

Tags: mysql, select

This query works fine:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PRODUKTY WHERE Id_sklep_kategorie IN(669, 670, 671, 672, 
                                            673, 674, 683, 686, 
                                            687, 688, 689, 690, 
                                            691, 692, 693, 694, 
                                            695, 696, 697, 698, 
                                            699, 700, 701, 845, 
                                            846, 847, 848, 849, 
                                            850, 851, 898);
```

But I want to have it more automatically, so I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM PRODUKTY WHERE Id_sklep_kategorie IN(SELECT Id_sklep_kategorie 
                                              FROM SKLEP_KATEGORIE);
```

- but it returns me all records...

How can I do this?

Comment: You query is correct. Check the results returned by sub query.

Comment: See any basic introduction to JOINs

Comment: Check how many `Id_sklep_kategorie` in `SKLEP_KATEGORIE` Table

Comment: not surprising. `SELECT Id_sklep_kategorie FROM SKLEP_KATEGORIE` selects all possible values, not just the subset you statically specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ought to return all the record as you are selecting all the `Id_sklep_kategorie` from inquery. Now that you have selected all the IDs from inquery, you will get all the records from your whole query. As per my understanding, you need to pass the IDs if you need those specific rows, as you have provided.

Comment: or store them in separate table, to make the query less messy